# How to attach a scroll event to a text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events, textinput

I'm trying to attach a scroll event to a text input so that when you scroll-up, while the textbox is focused, it increments the numbers in it and when you scroll-down it decrements the number in it. If it's empty or NaN it should just replace it with a 0 and continue on.

I've managed to pull this off for `touchmove` and click-and-`drag`, but for some reason  the scroll event isn't attaching to the text box.

http://jsfiddle.net/KBKA7/

```
$('input').scroll(function(event) {
    $('div').append('scrolled1');
});

$('input').add('.scrollable').on('scroll', function(event) {
    $('div').append('scrolled2');
});
```

No events are being fired.

Comment: Further to what Amit states, where are your scroll bars in the fiddle?

Comment: @LeeTaylor it's an empty textbox. I want to fill it with numbers based on the scroll event itself. Increment the number on scroll-up and decrement on scroll-down.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. There are no scrollbars on the text box. Therefore you will not receive a scroll event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

```
$('input').mousewheel(function(event) {
    $('div').append('scrolled ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KBKA7/2/

Comment: mousewheel != scroll

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the fact that `<input type="text">` cannot be scrolled.

Have you tried using `textarea`? It works fine.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KBKA7/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. At least in Jsfiddle. That's what's wrong with your answer. Otherwise I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: You have to type in the text area (so that it now scrolls) for it to work.